# Are there events that are truly unique objectively? Or are these categories subjective?

Tags: classification, events

What makes us put events into their natural kinds? For example, if someone wins the lottery after praying to the moon God, it might be the first time someone won after praying to the moon God. That person might classify that as an event of the first of its kind.

Another person might classify this event as belonging to the group of events categorized as “lottery wins that occurred after praying to a deity.” Since people have won lotteries after praying to a deity, this event is not seen as unique.

What makes people put events into categories? And what makes events unique?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the problem of induction really just the problem of similarity?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97349/is-the-problem-of-induction-really-just-the-problem-of-similarity)

Comment: @DavidGudeman What does this have to do with induction?

Comment: The other question had nothing to do with induction; it was an oblique way to ask this question. Asking the same question in different words doesn't make it another question.

Comment: Induction relies upon similarity @DavidGudeman. This question is about categorization and how people categorize things. Stop being obtuse.

Comment: Categorization relies on similarity.

Comment: Everything relies on similarity.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your question might be closed on the grounds that it is too vague.   All events can be considered objectively unique in the sense that they are specific instances. If I cough while typing this answer, the cough is a distinct event, and the only one of its kind occurring under those circumstances. In physics, my cough might be considered as a distinct event at a point in spacetime.

There is no established taxonomy for classifying events, and the scope for classification is virtually endless. To return to my cough, I could classify that in any number of ways, for instance: a type of sound, a human activity, an involuntary activity, an activity performed during daylight, an activity performed in a sedentary position, an activity performed on a Monday, an activity performed by a male, an activity performed by a 63 year old, an activity performed indoors, an activity performed by me, etc ad nauseam. Clearly each of those classifications covers a multitude of events. However, you can combine them to narrow the focus down to a single, unique event, eg by considering the category of involuntary sounds made by me at a given date and time.

Quite why someone might want to categorise events in a particular way is too open a question.

Comment: I did not know you were 63, kudos to your usually helpful answers!

Comment: @thinkingman cheers! And thank you for your endlessly thought-provoking questions!

Answer (score 0):

> Another person might classify this event as belonging to the group of events categorized as “lottery wins that occurred after praying to a deity.” Since people have won lotteries after praying to a deity, this event is not seen as unique.

Unless you can show conclusively a direct cause and effect between praying to a deity and winning the lottery, it's merely coincidence. I can't answer to the psychology of assigning and characterizing infrequent events. Its the same psychology that drives the belief in lucky charms like rabbits foot (feet?) to encourage infrequent events like winning the lottery.